# Jquery .click only fire on condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hey I am trying to get a function to only enact when class2 has not been appended to class1:

```js
$("#div").on('mouseenter', 'class1:not(.class2)', function() {
  $(".class1").fadeIn('fast', 0);

  anotherfunction();
});
```

```css
.class1 {
  position: relative;
  width: 181px;
  height: 381px;
  background: transparent url(/img/phone2.png) center center no-repeat;
  opacity: 1;
  cursor: crosshair;
  background-size: 100%;
  z-index: 1000;
}
.class1 .class2 {
  background-color: cyan;
}
.class1 .class3 {
  -webkit-transition: opacity 300ms;
  transition: opacity 300ms;
  position: absolute;
  top: 88px;
  left: 21px;
  right: 20px;
  bottom: 92px;
  background: transparent;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Class3 is inside class1... could that be causing the problem?

```html
<div class="Class1">
  <div class="Class3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: show your html as well if the missing `.` is not the problem..

Comment: class names are case sensitive. If you use `Class1` in html you need to use `Class1` in css as well (*and jquery selectors*). Not `class1`

Answer (score 2):

Should be:

```
$("#div").on('mouseenter', '.class1:not(.class2)', function() {
                            ^
```

And probably you need to change

```
$(".class1").fadeIn('fast', 0);
```

to

```
$( this ).fadeIn('fast', 0);
```

Comment: Show also how class is presented in your code. Information you've provided is still not enough

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jquery function .has(selector) to check if an element has a children that fits the selector by checking if the length property of the returned array is bigger than zero. For example:

```
if(!$(".class1").has(".class2").length)
     triggerFunction();
```

But you should be careful, since this statement will always return false, if ANY element with the classname "class1" has a child with a class "class2". If your element with id "div" is also the element with the classname "class1", then you can simply check for it's children using

```
if(!$(this).has(".class2").length)
```

in your .on() method.

Answer (score 0):

What you submitted: http://jsfiddle.net/d2ozz2rr/

My updated version: http://jsfiddle.net/d2ozz2rr/1/

Differences:

- HTML class names lowercased (as mentioned in the comments)
- `$("body")` instead of `$("#div")`.  `#div` looks for an element with `id="div"`. the way you are using `.on()` requires an ancestor element.  not sure why you didn't do `$(".class1:not(.class2)").on('mouseenter', function () {`
- `'class1'` missing `.` (as mentioned in another answer)